# http request taking too long time waiting for server response

Tags: wordpress, server, http-get, latency, server-response

We are using 3rd party website monitoring system to see if certain pages are loading well.

I often see monitor showing up that it took more than 8-9 seconds to load our checkout page as shown picture below:

[image]

our website is redirecting from non www to www, and then http to https, so I understand couple redirection can happen.  What I don't understand what could be the reason that the page request is taking 2-3 seconds on waiting?

Comment: why two redirects? You can trivially test for `if (!ssl || !www)` and do a single redirect, regardless of which "thing" is missing.

Comment: do you happen to know how to properly redirect both ssl and www with wordpress?

Comment: What are your WordPress Addressed and Site URLs in admin?

Comment: Both are set as: https : // www . example . com and htaccess has the very basic wordpress code only...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This commonly happens when you have WordPress Address and Site URLs as non-www and non-https, but redirect in .htaccess, wp-config.php or via a plugin for both www and https. (Or, the host is doing the redirects for you.) You need to configure the WordPress Address and Site URLs for both www and https to avoid the redirects; that's the most inefficient way.

If you do that and set the monitor to request the www and https page, and you still see long TTFB (Time to First Byte) times, it's a slow host.

Comment: I think the monitor is initially requesting as `http://example.com` and it is redirecting to `https://www.example.com/` as my wordpress home and site url are both set as `https://www.example.com`  Then I am still wondering why I would have to see such long wait time like 2.12s, 1.79s, 3.2s, and 2.03 seconds to finally start loading the wordpress contents?? hmmm...

Comment: Set the monitor to request the www and https page; if you still see long TTFB times, it's a slow host.

Comment: I have the same problem...the website is rediricting 3 times causing the TTFB to be more than 15 seconds...How can I remove this redirection in wordpress?

Comment: Hi @markratledge, I am interested on the solution you suggest. Could you please elaborate more on it or share a link with additional information?